# Composition Series Analogous to Compactness?

Tags: group-theory, compactness

The wikipedia page for [group with operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_with_operators#Applications) makes the following claim about composition series as being analogous to compactness:

> The Jordan–Hölder theorem also holds in the context of operator
>   groups. The requirement that a group have a composition series is
>   analogous to that of compactness in topology, and can sometimes be too
>   strong a requirement. It is natural to talk about "compactness
>   relative to a set", i.e. talk about composition series where each
>   (normal) subgroup is an operator-subgroup relative to the operator set
>   X, of the group in question.

Does anybody have any comments on this, preferably with links/references? Gonna require outside-the-box thinking on this one, but the intro to Zassenhaus' group theory motivating taking composition series is definitely in the spirit of compactness:

> The idea of Holder for solving this problem was later made a general
>   principle of investigation in algebra by E. Noether. We are  referring
>   to the consistent application of the concept of homomorphic mapping.
>   With such mappings one views the objects, so to speak, through the
>   wrong end of a telescope. These mappings, applied to finite groups,
>   give rise to the concepts of normal subgroup and of factor group.
>   Repeated application of the process of diminution yields the
>   composition series, whose factor groups are the finite simple groups.
>   These are, accordingly, the bricks of which every finite group is
>   built.

when you view [compactness as a *local-to-global* principle](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/preprints/compactness.pdf).

Thanks!